Matching comma separated value in a table against input parameter
I have data in a table column which is comma separated and I can pass any one of the value as input parameter  and it should match the string of that one and return respective value from other column



Column 1
Column 2
Column 3




X
A 1.0, A 2.0, A 3.0
test


Y
B
test


Z
null
test



Now whether I give input a A 1.0, A 2.0 or A 3.0 it should return X and if I pass input B it should return Y based on column 3 condition where column 3=test

SO is no code writing service. What have you tried and what doesn't work as expected?

Why keep all the values of A in one field. I would recommend you to convert that string to an array and unnest it, which can be done by:-
    select column1, unnest(STRING_TO_ARRAY(column2,',')) as column2, column3 
    from your_table 
    where cond1 = 'something';

